# Cannot generate a service in an Ionic Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Whenever I try to generate a service within my Ionic Angular web application, using `ng g s [service-name]` I keep running into this error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
```

I tried creating a test Angular project, which manages to generate services just fine.

I have tried changing my version of Angular, which leads to various dependency conflicts, and I am currently working with version 14.0.4 of the Angular CLI. I have also tried using Ionic to generate a service instead (`ionic generate`), but no dice.

Comment: Ionic uses  the 'ionic' keyword for their cli operations, have you tried that? I.E: ionic generate service service-name . More here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate

Comment: @Tommi I have, yes, I can add that to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng add @angular-eslint/schematics@next.
If it still doesn’t work, downgrade Angular to v.13 and be sure to use Ionic v.5.
If it still doesn’t work, try to reinstall ionic.